# list arrays in Drupal form

Tags: drupal, forms, arrays

Is there a better way to find all form elements in a Drupal form than doing a print_r($form)?  This dumps excessive amount of information and it is no obvious what to look for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module give you access to various debugging tools, like `dpm` which prints data like arrays much cleaner than `print_r` using krumo.

Another option if you use firefox would be to [Drupal For Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8370?src=api)

Comment: I got dpm($form) working. Nice!  This is much better way to view data.  I am still trying to figure out where stuff is coming from eg: location longitude & latitude. The word 'longitude' is referenced in 10 different places.  Eg: I thought this was a likely place to isolate text box for this input field.
dpm($form['#field_info']['field_store_latitude']['location_settings']['form']['fields']);